# How to use JQuery to focus on a specific DIV tag?

Tags: jquery

Say I got a few DIV tags in a HTML page like:

```
<DIV ID="all">
    <DIV ID="div1">              
    <Input type="radio" name="data['site1']['user']" VALUE="1">user1<br/>
    </DIV>
    <DIV ID="div2">              
    <Input type="radio" name="data['site1']['user']" VALUE="2">user2<br/>
    </DIV>
    <DIV ID="div3">              
    <Input type="radio" name="data['site1']['user']" VALUE="3">user3<br/>
    </DIV>
    <DIV ID="div4">              
    <Input type="radio" name="data['site1']['user']" VALUE="4">user4<br/>
    </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Is it possible to do the same effect in JQuery like this:

```
Document.getElementByID('div2').focus();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent of that is:

```
$("#div2").focus();
```

but you can only focus on a form element so:

```
$("#div2 :input").focus();
```

will focus on the first form element inside the element with ID div2.

Answer (score 3):

You can't set focus on `div` elements, only the following elements are "focusable":

- `A`
- `AREA`
- `LABEL`
- `INPUT`
- `SELECT`
- `TEXTAREA`
- `BUTTON`

If you have some element that can receive focus inside your div, get it with your selector, otherwise, the most similar behavior I could think, is [*scrolling*](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) to the element...

Answer (score 2):

You can't focus on a div. But if you want to focus on the radio button within div2, you can try:

```
$('#div2 input').focus();
```